# How do I resolve annotations for Room library in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, android-room

I'm following [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#kotlin) on Room for SQLite in kotlin. This is the first step where they have a User entity

```
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") val firstName: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") val lastName: String?
)
```

I'm getting IDE errors of Unresolved references on all these annotations.

I'm completely new to this. I couldn't find any info on how do I annotate in Kotlin. Basically, I don't know how to annotate in Kotlin.

Do I need a library dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of error happens and you haven't declared the dependencies in your `build.gradle`.

Also, as mentioned in the page that you sent:

> Note: In order to use Room in your app, declare Room dependencies in your app's build.gradle file.

List of dependencies can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#declaring_dependencies)

So, add Room dependencies to your build.gradle as follows (you can add one by one and check which one fixes the issue:

```
dependencies {
  def room_version = "2.2.2"

  implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
  annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version" // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor

  // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
  implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

  // optional - RxJava support for Room
  implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"

  // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
  implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"

  // Test helpers
  testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
}
```

Add them and perform a Sync. Then, those errors should be gone